# Recyclerview Checkbox state changing

Tags: android, button, fragment

I have floating action button in my fragment. how can I enable or disable checkboxes inside the recyclerview by using this floating action button. Both recycler view and floating action button are inside the same fragment activity. Also, I need to hide this floating action button upon recyclerview scrolling.

Comment: use interface to contact fragment

Comment: If you are receiving button click in activity, then add a `function()` in fragment, then on button click call `fragment.function()` in your activity

Comment: please show your code

Comment: how to use interface to contact fragment

Comment: you can use ViewModel also.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please review.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want oo add something to your layout in fragment you can do something like this:

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutFragment = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.fragmentLayout);
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //if you want to add something to your Linearlayout fragment
           //remove all views for example
           linearLayoutFragment.removeAllViews();
        }
 });
```